# SQLAlchemy allow null as ForeignKey

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

Let's say I have two models:

```py
class EntityModel(DB.Model):
  id = DB.Column(DB.Unicode(37), primary_key=True)

class DocumentModel(DB.Model):
  id = DB.Column(DB.Unicode(37), primary_key=True)
  entity_id = DB.Column(DB.Unicode(37), DB.ForeignKey('entity.id', ondelete='cascade'), nullable=True)
  entity = DB.relationship('EntityModel')
```

I can create a new Document with entity_id NULL. But once I set valid entity_id to that document I cannot set it back to null. I get this error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

How can I set entity_id back to null after it had a valid entity_id?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

your ORM definition looks fine, DocumentModel.entity_id is nullable indeed. What I would do in this case is check the actual table definition in MySQL and make sure it corresponds with your ORM definition, e.g.

```
-- make sure DocumentModel.entity_id is nullable :
SHOW CREATE TABLE DocumentModel\G 
UPDATE DocumentModel.entity_id SET entity_id = NULL WHERE entity_id = XXX;
```

Comment: This is possible.  The point I was trying to make in my answer is that you really shouldn't do this.  Having a NULL key is essentially an orphaned record.  It adds management later on and almost always requires cleanup.   JMHO.

Answer (score -1):

null is not valid for a child row.  As an alternative, make a parent that is only used for 'null' children and set key to that id.  I don't really understand the purpose of this as you do not want orphan records.  If the relationship is not really 1 to many with a parent child relationship, then you should consider a different relationship type or maybe add a field to make child records inactive.

Comment: It does not make sense, but MySQL is perfectly fine with it. It allows child records to be set to null.

Comment: Hi, Sebi.  It simply has to do with data integrity.  If you do not enforce relationships, then this is allowed.  BUT, it can result in orphaned records.  I would say that this is bad 99.9% of the time.